# Get Error : Package react-native-gesture-handler has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration

Tags: react-native

I try to use react navigation but get errors like : *Package react-native-gesture-handler has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Cannot find module 'react-native-gesture-handler\package.json'*

my json package looks like :

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.1.0",
    "expo": "~36.0.0",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.5.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.1.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I get this eror every time install a new package. I run yarn install to resolve all dependencies again and it works.